Curly quotation marks in Notepad on WIndows 11
I just pressed a hotkey in Notepad that has permanently changed it so that when I use the " key, they are output as curly instead of straight. What did I press? I am not using AHK or any other third-party software.

Note: "what did I press?" is not equivalent to "how can I change it back?". Maybe the keystroke toggles the behavior, maybe not. I'm pointing this out in case maybe you're asking not (or not everything) what you really want to know.

Do the curly quotation marks show up when you save the file and open it in a different editor? (i.e. is this an input issue or a display issue?)

(Found by accident - Tested on Windows 11)
Ctrl-Shift-" (or ' works too)
When you press the above key combination - it will look like nothing happened - but the toggle already happened. Press the same key combination to toggle it back to normal.
The next ' or " will go from the straight version into curly ‘’ and “” respectively.

Hot key shown in answer does not seem to have any effect on Windows 10 Notepad v 22H2 (OS Build 19045.5131)

Notepad on win 10 and win 11 are very different app.

Darius -- Thanks for pointing out the app difference. I was curious if that capability existed on Windows 10 Notepad.

thank you for testing and confirming :).
